# how does facebook authentication work?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, browser, cookies

I use Linux and Google chrome as browsers. I know that cookies are stored **/home/gio/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies** but deleting this file and restarting browser doesn't do anything.

When I visit facebook I'm still logged in. I did little bit of research and it turn out that modern websites use localstorage instead of cookies.

Then I deleted both 
**/home/gio/.config/google-chrome/Default/Local Storage** and the cookies file too.

I restarted the browser but I'm still logged in.

So I'm interested how does this concept work and where is my information stored in the browser?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox both store active session information in their cache databases, so deleting site localstorage or cookies won't delete session persistance. Instead try installing Bleachbit, and run it with the Chromium options "Current Session" and "Cache" checked. after that, you should no longer be able to access the site without logging in again.

Comment: If i delete cache database and restart chrome will i be still logged in? Where is cache database located?

Comment: `~/.cache/google-chrome` on debian-based systems, but I really don't recommend you attempt to delete it manually. Either use Bleachbit or the Chrome tools for clearing history.